# Debugging Python C extensions in Mavericks

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, gdb, lldb

I've been writing C extensions to Python for a while, but have been on other tasks for the past year or so. It looks like I'm going to come back to this soon, but in the meantime I've upgraded my Mac to Mavericks. And of course, suddenly, EEK! GDB is gone! And I can't find a startup file for LLDB (like the existing GDB version in Misc/gdbinit) that knows how to reach into the CPython interpreter and tell me about objects. (Or any easy Emacs-LLDB integration like I had with GDB.)

What's the consensus on the best way to debug C extensions now? Go build a custom GDB? Learn LLDB and write my own integration? Use some IDE that 'just does' all this? Just stop trying to do this on a Mac and do it in Linux instead?

(Just to make things even more fun, I need to do this in Python 2.6 to be compatible with our existing RHEL installations... which means I also need to fix the readline bug that causes Python 2.6 to crash on Mavericks -- and that's how I discovered these issues. Sigh.)